# System user converted to cpanel users

Tags: cpanel

I installed an app that created it's own system user and I want to use cPanel to created the DB and manage mail and other services.

So is there any way to convert a linux user to be a cPanel user?

I am running WHM 11.44.1 build 11 and CentOS 6.5.
I have full root access to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the cPanel forums at the same time and according to cPanel Employee cPanelMicheal:

> Hello
>
> It's likely a better idea to simply remove the user manually, and then
>   create a cPanel account for it. This way the user will still exist on
>   the system, and the cPanel account is setup successfully. You may need
>   to update ownership for files related to that application after
>   re-creating it because the UID is likely to change.
>
> Thank you.

According to forum post: [Thread: System user converted to cpanel users](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/system-user-converted-cpanel-users-422361.html)